# XSI Namespace Copied To Result Sequence

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-3.0

I have an XML file containing a bunch of look-ups.  A simplified version below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parties xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/usr/local/share/xml/schema/quantile/Parties.xsd">
    <Party name="Bens Birthday">
        <ZIP>AB1234</ZIP>
        <EMAIL>foo@bar.com</EMAIL>
        <ATTENDEES>
            <ATTENDEE>Bob</ATTENDEE>
            <ATTENDEE>David</ATTENDEE>
        </ATTENDEES>
    </Party>
</Parties>
```

I've written a simple XSD to validate this data:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Parties">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Party" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ZIP" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="EMAIL" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="ATTENDEES" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="ATTENDEE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                             </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This works well.

I'm loading the XML file into an XSLT and using it as a look-up within the transform.

```
<xsl:variable name="party-details" select="document($party-file)/Parties"/>
<xsl:variable name="party-map" select="$party-details/Party[@name='Bens Birthday']"/>
```

This works well when I'm interrogating a text node:

```
<FOO>{$party-map/EMAIL}</FOO>
```

But if I try to do the same with a sequence:

```
<xsl:sequence select="$party-map/ATTENDEES/ATTENDEE"/>
```

I inherit the namespace definition from the Party XML File:

```
<Parties xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/usr/local/share/xml/schema/quantile/Parties.xsd">
```

Resulting in output like this:

```
<ATTENDEE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Bob</ATTENDEE>
```

Obviously if I remove the `xmlns:xsi` and `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` from the Party XML file, the problem goes away... but then I'm not validating it.

Ultimately this breaks my XSLT output validation as the `xsi` definition is not allowed on the `ATTENDEE` element.

I kinda see what's happening here - all children of `Parties` inherit the namespace xmlns:xsi, so when I splice the `ATTENDEE` sequence into my XSLT output, the lack of an `xsi` definition in the XSLT means the processor adds it in.  It doesn't do this for text nodes, I assume, because they have no concept of namespace, only the element carries this.

I can move the problem by defining xmlns:xsi elsewhere on an output element and parent of `ATTENDEE` in the XSLT.

This is still putting constraints on my output format tho.  It feels like I should be able to strip the namespace out, but I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

Any ideas?  Or if someone can categorically say this is impossible, any other suggestions - like use DTD instead, or leave the schema off the XML completely, and do the validation inside the XSLT perhaps?  I'm guessing now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `xsl:sequence` then, use `xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no"` e.g.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Parties/Party[@name = 'Bens Birthday']/ATTENDEES" copy-namespaces="no"/>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpU uses your sample as the primary input but of course you can do the same with your `<xsl:copy-of select="$party-map/ATTENDEES/ATTENDEE" copy-namespaces="no"/>`.